# How can I hide the bar at the bottom of the text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2019

At the bottom of the text editor in Visual Studio, there's a bar with "resize" and issues. I keep hitting this bar by accident and resizing my window, or invoking a menu that says "show the error list" (which I always have shown anyway". Since this bar is of no use to me, does anyone know a way that I can completely hide it and save myself these annoyances?

/edit: it's this bar here:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of which bar are you referring to ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot (sorry about the Excel in the background on the left, I just noticed that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the 'Show file health indicator' box under **Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Display**

Options screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try on **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars**, and uncheck the **"Show horizontal scrollbar"** (the first option on the image):

[image]

It does not hide everything on the scrollbar, but it might help!

Comment: That's good, but unfortunately it doesn't hide the "errors" pane, I'd really like to hide everything on that line if I possibly could, as again, that's something that I keep hitting with the mouse.